# Reactjs state in ternary operator is not changed

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the element based on components state. I am using ternary operator to  determine what should be shown.

In render function i am doing something like this

`<li onClick={this.handleClick}>{(this.state.route) ? "active" : ""}</li>`

and click handler is just updating the state using this.setState.

Anyone has an idea why is this not working?

Working example of my simplefied problem can be found here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/20231/)

Comment: If you checked the console you would see `Object {activeRoute: "elem1 "}`. So behaviour is correct, since the `'elem1 '` string is not equal to `'elem1'` string.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question.

Comment: @zerkms that was the problem...cheers

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me in jsfiddle:

```
render: function() {
    return <div>
        <ul>
            <li onClick={this.change}>elem1
            {this.state.activeRoute==="elem1"?"active":""}</li>
            <li onClick={this.change}>elem2
            {this.state.activeRoute==="elem2"?"active":""}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>;
},
```